# Threads update previous created thread variable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to do something as follows -

1. A thread is created
2. When new Thread is created it updates previous thread's variable `limit`
3. Progress repeats for 3rd Thread, i.e. this thread updates variable `limit` for Thread ID1 and ID2..

Here's some sample code

**Main Class**

```
public class TaskImplementer {
    public static int End;
    public static int threadCount = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;

    findEnd();

    while (i < threadCount) {
        if(isPossible()) {      // check for some condition
        createThread aThread = new createThread(i, End);
        aThread.start();
        }
        i++;
        //updateGUI();  //updateGUI - show working Threads
    }
    }

    private static void findEnd() {
    //updates End variable
    }

    private static boolean isPossible() {
    //.....
    //Check for a condition
    return false;

    }
}
```

**createThread class**

```
public class createThread extends Thread {
    private static int ID;
    private static int limit;
    private static int startfromSomething;

    public createThread(int ThreadID, int End) {
    ID = ThreadID;
    limit = End;
    }

    private void doSomething() {
    //does work
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    while(startfromSomething < limit) {
        doSomething();
    }
    TaskImplementer.i--;
    }

}
```

The variable `limit` needs to be updated by each Thread on successful creation. Is it possible, please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "When new Thread is created it updates previous thread's variable limit" - you make it sound like each thread has its own `limit` variable. It doesn't, because all your variables are static. It's hard to suggest anything when we don't really know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: it`possible. you need to share `AtomicInteger` across your threads (or such-like synchronized variable). By the way, naming your class like `CreateThread` (verb instead of noun) isn't widely distributed in Java community and confusing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sir, you are right about static limit, it shoudn't be static there.What I am roughly trying to implement is-

ID1 creation - ID1's limit = limit

ID2 creation - ID1's limit = limit/2
               ID2's limit = limit

ID3 creation - ID1's limit = limit/2
               ID2's limit = 3/4 * limit
               ID3's limit = limit

ID4 creation - ID1's limit = limit/4
               ID2's limit = 3/4 * limit
               ID3's limit = limit
               ID3's limit = limit/2

Comment: @user1670099: You're still not being clear at all. Edit your question with a thorough description of what you're trying to achieve. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (Additionally, prefer to implement Runnable rather than extending Thread.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have atomic integer inside you createThread class and also should hold available threads (createThread) object via a list then each time you want to run another thread you must add it to list and at the same time decrease or increase limit variable of other running thread via their reference in thread list , i mean you must implement something like thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic you have given in your steps you can create an array of CreateThread's and set the parameters for id and limit.

```
public class TaskImplementer {
    static int End;
    static int threadCount = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        CreateThread[] tasks = new CreateThread[threadCount];
        while (i < threadCount) {
            int j = 0;
            while (j <= i) {

                if (tasks[j] != null) {
                    // Set ID and limit
                    tasks[j] = new CreateThread(j, End);
                    tasks[j].start();
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly due to your usage of "static" where it shouldn't be used!
This is how it should look like:

```
public class CreateThread extends Thread {
   private int ID;
   private int limit;
   private static int startfromSomething; //Don't know about this one. If this value is the same for every thread, "static" is correct. Otherwise remove "static".

   public createThread(int ThreadID, int End) {
      ID = ThreadID;
      limit = End;
   }
}
```

"Static" is used if you want to share a field among all instances and static content of this class.

One more thing: Java code conventions want you to start your class names with a capital letter.